# Switching +12VDC by arduino

Tags: arduino, transistors

I am new to electronics, so please bear with me. I have next task to do:

I have programmed Arudino Mega 2560 to provide some arbitrary digital signals on predefined pins. This is to provide some kind of simulation that will bring signals to ICP DAS device DIs, so that it can count them. This simulation works, pins do change their state from HIGH to LOW and vice versa. ICP DAS DIs require +10+VDC, and will draw no more than 20mA current.

Logically, I need some NO switch that will allow +12VDC to ICP DAS Input when Arduino output is HIGH. I have been advised to buy a logic-level MOSFTET. By looking at the examples on internet, P-channel MOSFET is always used to switch the positive DC terminal for load, and N-channel MOSFET is always used to switch the ground (0VDC) for load.

For this reason I have bought p-channel tsm3401cx> I connected Arduino output to pin 1, +12VDC to pin 2, and pin3 to my voltmeter. When I measure voltage from arduino, I can see that it periodically jumps to 5VDC, and returns to 0V. When I connect transistor, as soon as I bring signal to source, no matter if signal on gate is LOW or HIGH, switch closes immediately. I have come to understanding that this is because of the difference between in polarity between the gate and the source (Vgs), which is always larger than the gate threshold.

So, how can I achieve what I need (switch +12VDC by +5VDC signal)? What kind of transistor do I need?

Edit:

Transistor output should be connected to ICP DAS digital input:

Contact: Wet Contact
Sink/Source (NPN/PNP): Sink/Source
On Voltage Level+10 VDC ~ +50 VDC
Off Voltage Level+4 VDC
Max.Input Impedance10 kΩ

Comment: Two of them, of different polarities.

Comment: What current do you need to take from +12 V output? I guess you need a small current, well below 1 mA. Then the right circuit is: use N channel logic level MOSFET; connect its Source to GND and its Gate to Arduino; connect its Drain to +12 via a resistor 1 kOhm or about; take the output from Drain to resistor node.

Comment: I can provide more details when you give more information about what kind of output at 0-12 V do you need.

Comment: There are also high side switches available with logic level control.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Can you provide some more information?

Comment: @Master I have edited the question with more information about the digital input that the output should be connected to.

Comment: The circuit suggested by @PeterSmith is good. May be, you can use more simple one: with no M2, R2=3.3kOhm, Swicthed Vout is connected to Drain of M1. However: I am not sure this simplified design gives enough output voltage for your load.

Comment: The specification "Max impedance is 10 kOhm" is strange: we need to know just MIN input impedance.

Comment: In case these specifications tell "The max output impedance of source is 10 kOhm - you can use simplified circuit with one MOSFET. Otherwise, it is better to use 2 MOSFETS, as suggested by Peter.

Comment: @Master: I think the specification should read "input impedance 10k" - there is a period immediately before those words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

The [TP0610K](http://www.vishay.com/docs/71411/tp0610k.pdf) is capable of over 100mA load current (see the datasheet) and the [2N7002K](http://www.vishay.com/docs/71333/2n7002k.pdf) will turn on properly in a 5V system.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO6tup.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the logic input to M1 goes high, M1 turns on, pulling the drain to (very close) to ground.

This pulls the gate of M2 low, turning it on in a low impedance state, powering up the switched power system.

Comment: Can you please tell me what would be the voltage on the n-channel output / p-channel gate? This would help me better understand how the circuit works, while I wait for the components to arrive. I tried to use simulation that you posted, but it gives me some warnings about spacing

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for clarification! Then this simplified circuit is reliable:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuloDX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

M1 is not IRF530, it is any N channel Logic Level MOSFET with max drain to source voltage 20 V or more. R2 must be rated for dissipation of 72 mW, it is two 0402 SMD resistors or one 0603 or larger SMD resistor with rated power 80 mW, or almost any leaded resitor.

Same circuit with BJT:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKpJkd.png)</sup>

Q1 must be a switching BJT with transition frequency 200-400 MHz, current transfer ratio h21 no smaller than 50 at collector current 10 mA and max collector - emitter voltage higher than 20 V. Plenty of BJTs are suitable.

Comment: Thanks, will try it out. I currently do not have any logic level N-channel MOSFETs. While I wait for them to arrive (it will be like 5 days), is this possible to achieve the same effect with a bipolar transistor?

Comment: Can you also please explain how does it work. You have brought 12VDC through resistor onto drain and ICP DAS input. Doesn't this mean that input will be high when the MOSFET is off, since the ICP DAS needs only positive voltage?

Comment: Yes, it is right. The real input voltage on output is almost 0, when M1 is conducting, as the channel resistance of M1 is below 1 Ohm. On the contrary, when Logic Input is Low (0 V), M1 is not conducting and the output voltage is defined by voltage divider R1:{input resistance of ICP DAS}. It is 2 kOhms : 10 kOhms. So, we get exactly 10 V from the supply voltage 12 V.

Comment: Yes, you can use bipolar NPN transistor. How fast switching do yo need?

Comment: The advantage of MOSFET for such design is that it inherently allows to get fast enough switching. As for BJT - we have a tradeof between logic output current and switching speed.

Comment: This is just for testing, maybe every 200ms

Comment: When logic input is low, I should not be having any output, that is, the input on ICP DAS should be Low, and not 10V. So, HIGH FROM arduino -> HIGH ON ICP DAS input, LOW on arduino -> LOW on ICP DAS input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39124/discussion-between-master-and-goran).